# woocommerce ajax error message

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a fixed header in my shop.
When I do not complete all required fields at the checkout page, Woocommerce will throw an error message. This is an Ajax message.
It will scroll all the way to the top of the body and ignoring my custom CSS for the container.

Is there a way to disable Ajax / jQuery for this? 
I already looked in all WooCommerce classes and tried several things (to much to mention), but this didn't solved my issue.

Regards,

Roland

Comment: It seems that the jQuery itself might be using the scrollTop() method which will actually move you to the top of the page. You need to search the JS codes of your shop for that method and then add some values in it. Example scrollTop(200) will scroll only up to 200px from top.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

in Assets/js/frontend there are 2 files:
1) checkout.js
2) checkout.min.js

remove the ScollTop in checkout.js and minified that file to checkout.min.js. Upload that file back to /assets/js/frontend

The woocommerce-error message does not scroll to top anymore.

Regards,

Roland